# How do I fetch a variable by the value  of another variable in HTML::Template::Pro?

Tags: perl, templates

```
<TMPL_LOOP NAME="loopname">
    <TMPL_VAR NAME="<TMPL VAR NAME="anothervariable">">
</TMPL_LOOP>
```

What I want to to is pretty much like this:

```
$a= 1;
$b = 'a';
print $$b;
```

As you see ,I need to refer to the variable whose name is contained in another variable,

but the above doesn't work..

Is there a way to work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=918281 : Proprocess the data you send to your template system, and put it into a form that it can understand (ie fixed hash key).